# Python tkinter radiobutton widget, color doesn't change

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm learning Python GUI on lynda.com and for some reason, my code doesn't work while the mentor's code works perfectly fine. I copied the mentor's work to my code but it still doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
win = tk.Tk()
win.title("Python GUI")

COLOR1 = "Blue"
COLOR2 = "Gold"
COLOR3 = "Red"

# Radiobutton Callback
def radCall():
    radSel = radVar.get()
    if   radSel == 1: win.configure(background=COLOR1)
    elif radsel == 2: win.configure(background=COLOR2)
    elif radsel == 3: win.configure(background=COLOR3)

# create three Radiobuttons using one variable
radVar = tk.IntVar()
rad1 = tk.Radiobutton(win, text=COLOR1, variable=radVar, value=1, command=radCall)
rad1.grid(column=0, row=5, sticky=tk.W, columnspan=3)

rad2 = tk.Radiobutton(win, text=COLOR2, variable=radVar, value=2, command=radCall)
rad2.grid(column=1, row=5, sticky=tk.W, columnspan=3)

rad3 = tk.Radiobutton(win, text=COLOR3, variable=radVar, value=3, command=radCall)
rad3.grid(column=2, row=5, sticky=tk.W, columnspan=3)

win.mainloop()
```

The problem is, whenever I click on the Blue radiobutton, it works, while gold and red gives me error on my terminal.

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "radiobuttonwidget.py", line 60, in radCall
    elif radsel == 2: win.configure(background=COLOR2)
NameError: name 'radsel' is not defined
```

Same for elif radsel == 3

Comment: What is `win` in this context? And what is the error that you get?

Comment: Updated my question. win = tk.Tk()

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined your variable as radSel and in your Loop, you try to use radsel. Change the "s" to "S". This should be the problem.